# Can a company in Germany lets its employee to work some months from iran remotely?

Tags: germany, sanctions, work-permit, iran

As an Iranian,I am trying to get an stable, trustable job from Germany,and move there. but i want to work for some months remotely from iran. Due to some problems i cant completely leave home.
I had a friend like that, but because company customers changed to americans,he had to move to Germany.

So, its not probably possible for me to find a job like that, isnt it???

Comment: Germany is a very important country for Iranians because of their good behavior with Iranian employees, even there are u.s sanctions. Almost nobody else is like that. So this questions sounds more logical, acceptable. Tnx

Comment: Iran is under [german embargo for several goods](https://www.bafa.de/DE/Aussenwirtschaft/Ausfuhrkontrolle/Embargos/Iran/iran_node.html) since 2011 or longer.

Comment: Even if a company could set up ways to do this legally, asking for this would make you a less attractive applicant. Some companies offer a "workation" benefit, but that's already a legal grey area and will probably be restricted to EU countries. Working from outside the EU raises all kinds of security and data protection concerns that are simply not worth solving unless you would be an unusually valuable employee.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

- A German company will face tax and accounting issues if they have an *employee* (as opposed to a *contractor*) outside Germany. If the employee lives and works somewhere in the EU, those issues can be resolved more easily than for countries outside the EU, but either way the company would be **unlikely to do that** unless the prospective employee has unique skills which cannot be found elsewhere.
  There still seems to be a [double tax agreement](https://www.bgbl.de/xaver/bgbl/start.xav?startbk=Bundesanzeiger_BGBl&jumpTo=bgbl269s2133b.pdf#__bgbl__%2F%2F*%5B%40attr_id%3D%27bgbl269s2133b.pdf%27%5D__1703876692863) between Germany and Iran, even if it was originally signed with the "Kaiserreich Iran," so it is not completely impossible. But *not impossible* is not the same as *likely*.
- Due to the sanctions against Iran, a company would be **even less likely to do that** in the case of Iran. They would risk secondary sanctions from the US.
- The Gaza crisis may lead to additional German sanctions against Iran if Iran is seen as hostile to Israel. Few companies would take the risk of taking on employees or even contractors from Iran right now.